# React Router Dom Nested Switch problem. How to make a rerender after clicking on Link?

Tags: react-router-dom

**Issue**: Address bar changes on clicking Link button, but the component doesn't actually render. Which is Im unsure about is rather its not mounting to DOM at all or is it just not rendering out from DOM.

**Code to reproduce**: My code looks very similar to this:

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  const isAuth = false;

  return (
    <Switch>
      {!isAuth && (
        <Route path={'/auth'}>
          <NestedSwitchComponent />
        </Route>
      )}
      ){isAuth ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Redirect to={'/auth'} />}
    </Switch>
  );
};

export const NestedSwitchComponent = () => {
    
    const arrayWithPathsAndComponents = [{
        path: 'login',
        Component: LoginForm
    },{
        path: 'register',
        Component: RegisterForm
    }] 

    return (
    <>
        
        <Link
          to={'/auth/login'}
        >
        <Link
          to={'/auth/register'}
        >
        <Switch>
          {arrayWithPathsAndComponents.map(({ path, Component }) => (
            <Route
                key={path}
                path={"/auth" + path}
                component={Component}
            ></Route>
           ))}
        </Switch>
    </>)
};
```

Comment: If I'm missing out on something or if you have more questions - I'm more than happy to answer them!